# Is there a way to filter out the objects with a blank name in the AD attribute 'ManagedBy'?

Tags: powershell

I don't have enough reputation points (lurker here for years though, good stuff!) so I have to ask a new question rather than commenting on Apologician's original post.  Here is Apologician's code:

```
$test = 'OU=example,DC=example,DC=test'

$test | ForEach {Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy -SearchBase $_ } |
 Select Name, ManagedBy |
 Sort -Property Name |
 Out-File C:\test.csv
```

I want to capture the names of objects with a blank ManagedBy field.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `-LDAPFilter` parameter and supply the raw query filter `(!(managedBy=*))`: `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(!(managedBy=*))' -Properties ManagedBy`

Comment: Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(!managedby=*)" -Properties ManagedBy |
    Select-Object samAccountName, Manager, Description #|
    #Export-Csv -Path .\AllNullManagedBy.csv -NoTypeInformation. 

How can I point is to a specific OU rather than searching the entire AD?  THANKS!

Comment: For that you can use the `-SearchBase` parameter

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any `-Filter` expressions that would translate correctly, but you can supply a raw LDAP query filter to the `-LDAPFilter` parameter that describes groups with a blank `managedBy` attribute:

```
# Fetch groups with no manager
$unmanagedGroups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(!(managedBy=*))' -Properties Manager,Description -SearchBase 'OU=example,DC=example,DC=test' |Select SAMAccountName,Manager,Description

# Export to CSV
$unmanagedGroups |Export-Csv -Path .\path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The filter clause `managedBy=*` resolves any group that *has* a value in the `managedBy` attribute, the `!` inverts the clause so it only resolves groups for which that *isn't* the case

Comment: I think it just translates to `"managedby -notlike '*'"` for filter

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you'd think so, but it doesn't allow for wildcards when using attributes with DN-syntax, so `-notlike` is not an option, and using `-ne` will cause the query parser to escape `*` and search for it literally :)

Comment: Lets say my -SearchBase = 'OU=Computers,OU=CompanyName,DC=Domain,DC=com' BUT in the Computers OU there are many other OU's i.e (Administrators, Accounting, Finance, etc.)  I get no output pointing at the Computers OU, but if I point to 'OU=CompanyName,DC=Domain,DC=com' I will get all of the blank ManagedBy objects in the entire AD.  I'm trying to just search the Computers OU and all of the sub OUs within Computers.

Comment: Just tried it against an OU same user count for both LDAP filter and AD filter. I think the parser just translates it to the same ldap syntax

Comment: @user2635584 Are there any `group` objects in the `Computers` OU? Sounds like that kind of name you'd give to an OU that contains `computer` objects, not groups :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm a powershell newbie (using it sporadically for years) and now that you've pointed it out, it seems completely obvious now.  So now I have to figure out how to use Get-ADComputers with the Get-ADGroup command?   Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @KellyConger what's the relationship between the groups and the computer accounts? Are the computer accounts members of the groups you want to report on?

Comment: I'm trying to find all of the servers and client computers that have a blank ManagedBy field.  Seemed like a simple request at first.  :)

Comment: @KellyConger principals (users and computers) don't have a `managedBy` attribute - but they might have a `manager` attribute for similar purposes - so `Get-ADComputer -Filter '(!(manager=*))'` will give you what you want, but it's likely just going to be "all computers", filling it in for computer accounts in AD is uncommon in my experience.